# How to set Java Card Application Identifier(AID) of the applet in Eclipse 4.2

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, applet, javacard

I'm a newbie java card programming. I write the java card applet and application on Eclipse 4.2 that is bunched with Android SDK.

I have a question. How to set the Application ID of my Java Card applet in Eclipse. Is there any Eclipse Plugin to set Application ID of Java Card Applet?

Answer (score 0):

Not in Eclipse itself no, because it doesn't come with a Java Card development environment. You are limited to compiling into byte code, but conversion to the Java Card byte code is missing (conversion to `.cap files`). You can however call the Java Card converter (of the Oracle Java Card development kit) using an Ant build script.

A quick search brought up the [EclipseJCDE plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-jcde/).

NXP also supplies the JCOP Java Card development environment based on Eclipse (since Eclipse 2.0 - initially created by IBM BlueZ), but distribution is limited.

Comment: I can set Application Identifier via Java Card Converter?

Comment: @thsecmaniac, yes you can. Use the `-applet` option. Examples (of an old version of Sun/Oracle's tools) are here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/applet-136808.html. Note that you will need to provide AIDs during installation as well (if your card uses Global Platform for card management).